# Gmail stopped syncing messages

Tags: sync, samsung-nexus-s, gmail

For some reason, Gmail on my Nexus S is not pulling new messages anymore. I added a second Gmail account; could it possibly be the reason?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not getting messages? Is it possible notifications are just turned off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second account probably has nothing to do with the other.

You'll want to go to `Menu | Settings | Accounts & sync` and click on the account that's not working. Ensure that "Sync Gmail" is checked.

If that doesn't help, then you should try [what I do for all truculent apps](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it).

- Force stop

if that doesn't help

- Clear cache

if that doesn't help

- Clear data

if that doesn't help

- Restart the phone (turn off/turn on the phone, unless you have a "restart" option)

and if that still doesn't help, try the nuclear option:

- uninstall and re-install

Comment: before you start clearing the cache and data, I would restart the phone, or try to turn off the data connection. if that doesn't work, then clear the cache and data. no need to lose the data if you don't need to.

Comment: Thank you, it works! For some reason, sync was stopped in the settings...